# How to convert a MS Office 2013 application created with office 64 bit version to one that is compatible with Office 32-bits?

Tags: ms-access, 32bit-64bit, ms-access-2013

I have developed a Microsoft Office application using Office 2013 64-bit edition.
After reading how it is still recommended for most users (even on Windows 64-bits machines)to use Office 32-bits, I came to know what I did is wrong, and my application need to run on many clients with mostly office 32-bits.
Is there anyway I can convert my MS Access file to be compatible with a 32-bit version?

Answer (score 1):

If your application is not being distributed as a compiled (an accDE), and it does not use any API calls, then you should not have to change anything to run the application with x32 version of Access.

So no converting is required. Note that if you distribution a compiled version (accDE), then yes you need to re-compile your application using x32 version of Access. So incompatibility ONLY exists if you distribution a compiled application. Because users cannot modify nor change compiled applications, then Access can not re-compile on the fly when moving the application between x32 and x64 versions. When distribution an accDB standard file, then Access will detect this issue and re-compile your code without any user intervention required.

With your given information, no changes are required and an application written using x32 or x64 versions of Access will run on either system without requiring changes.

So your existing application should run just fine using the x32 version of Access. As noted the only issues are that of using compiled applications, or if your application uses any custom API calls. Such API calls can also be made compatible between x32 and x64 via conditional compile options. However, as noted, such changes are ONLY required if you using API calls.

If you are by chance using any API calls, then how to create an application that runs on both x32 and x64 is outlined here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700513(v=office.11).aspx